# after calling TNSMutableDictionary.Create do we need to call release?

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey

after reading the excelent post from Dalija Prasnikar [iOS objective-c object: When to use release and when to not use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52314334/ios-objective-c-object-when-to-use-release-and-when-to-not-use-it) I learned :

> Methods whose name begins with alloc, new, copy, or mutableCopy don't
>   require calls to retain. On the contrary, if you call it you will
>   create a memory leak because there will be one retain too many. But
>   they do require release or autorelease. Those object instances are the
>   ones you have created, and under Objective-C they are automatically
>   retained when constructed.

However what about the create ? for exemple doing `myDict: = TNSMutableDictionary.Create` do I need later to call `myDict.release`?

what is exactly the difference between

```
TNSMutableDictionary.Wrap(TNSMutableDictionary.Wrap(TNSMutableDictionary.OCClass.alloc).init);
```

and

`TNSMutableDictionary.Create` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** Yes, you need to call `release` if you used `Create` (`TNSMutableDictionary.Create`)

For construction of the object it does not really matter much which variant you use, but shorter is always more readable. And you have way to many wrappings in your Objective-C version.

---

#### Constructing object instances Delphi vs Objective-C

The process of constructing an object on the Objective-C is a bit different from 
the process of constructing Delphi object instances.

While Delphi constructs objects in one go, by invoking a constructor that triggers memory allocation for the object instance and then initializes the object, in Objective-C that process is divided into two steps. One is memory allocation, done with the
`alloc` method and the next is initialization that is done through various named `init`
methods. Both of these are close equivalents of different parts of Delphi constructors.

But that is not all. Objective-C also has `new` which combines `alloc` and `init` in one go, similar to what Delphi constructor does. However, `new` calls only default constructor and if you need to use custom constructors then you need to use `alloc` + `initxxx` variant. For code consistency, Objective-C developers often prefer `alloc` + `init` even when they could use `new`.

#### Delphi wrappers for Objective-C objects

Delphi accesses Objective-C objects as raw pointers through a generic wrapper class. That class provides several class methods for easier instantiation of Objective-C objects.

`Create` is the equivalent of calling `alloc.init` or `new`, and invokes default
initialization, while `Alloc` is the equivalent of calling `alloc`, after which we have to invoke the appropriate initialization routine - some `initxxx` or default `init`

`Wrap` method is used to wrap already constructed object instance provided by the OS and to hold that object instance alive we must call `retain`, and after we are done `release`.

However, if you use `Wrap` merely to wrap object instance that **you have created** with `alloc.init` variants or `new`, then you should not call `retain`, and you must call `release`.

Comment: thanks @dalija, so all the firemonkey delphi source code is wrong with memory leaks :( just look in it for TNSMutableDictionary.Create, you will see they never call release :( same with all other NS***.create, they never (or rarely) call release :(

Comment: Anything is possible... Problem is that when you write code in Objective-C, ARC does its job there and you don't have to call retain and release. So you can create dictionary and pass it on without thinking about it any more. But Delphi ARC is separate from iOS/macOS ARC, if you construct object on Delphi side, OS ARC relies on you to signal when it is safe to release it. It can only do intermittent reference counting when you pass that object back to some OS API - but that counting will not make final release.

Comment: I have double, checked and triple checked, just to be on the safe side, and yes, you have to call `release` or you will leak the dictionary.

Comment: Thanks, @dalija ... I will create a bug report on quality.embarcadero.com about all these memories leaks

Comment: Note that Delphi's ARC for class objects on mobile platforms will be [going away in 10.4](http://blog.marcocantu.com/blog/2018-october-Delphi-ARC-directions.html), so proper memory management will become even more important.